# NullPointerException with json feeder in tests scope with gatling and scalatest

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest, gatling

I am trying to develop some tests with the scalatest framework to my gatling project but I'm not able to load the jsonFile I'm using inside this project.

I'm always having a nullPointerException.

I did a copy of my resources directory I'm using in the main folder to the test one but it's never recognized. Do I have to specify a data folder especially for this scope ?

Here's my build configuration inside my pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Default values -->
                        <!--<configFolder>src/test/resources</configFolder-->
                        <dataFolder>src/main/resources/data</dataFolder>
                        <resultsFolder>target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                        <!--&lt;!&ndash;<requestBodiesFolder>src/test/resources/request-bodies</requestBodiesFolder>-->
                        <simulationsFolder>src/main/scala</simulationsFolder>
                        <simulationClass>com.awesomecompany.scenarios.Scenarios</simulationClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalastyle</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalastyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
                <!--<configLocation>${basedir}/lib/scalastyle_config.xml</configLocation>-->
                <!--<outputFile>${project.basedir}/scalastyle-output.xml</outputFile>-->
                <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the stack trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.gatling.core.config.GatlingFiles$.dataDirectory(GatlingFiles.scala:38)
    at io.gatling.core.config.Resource$.feeder(Resource.scala:64)
    at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport$class.jsonFile(FeederSupport.scala:40)
    at io.gatling.core.Predef$.jsonFile(Predef.scala:32)
    at com.mycompany.tools.ScenarioParserTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScenarioParserTest.scala:19)
    at com.mycompany.tools.ScenarioParserTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ScenarioParserTest.scala:18)
    at com.mycompany.tools.ScenarioParserTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ScenarioParserTest.scala:18)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1647)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1644)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:390)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:427)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: For me, `mvn clean` and re-running this end up fixing it.  Not positive why, but I think I had a stale class definition from before a package rename.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration isn't set.

I don't know what you're doing exactly, but beware that you're hacking Gatling's internals, which are subjects to change anytime without notice.